# Python analog of Unix 'which'

Tags: python, bash

In *nix systems one can use `which`  to find out the full path to a command. For example:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

or `whereis` to show all possible locations for a given command

```
$ whereis python
python: /bin/python.exe /bin/python2.5-config /usr/bin/python.exe /usr/bin/python2.5-config /lib/python2.4 /lib/python2.5 /usr/lib/python2.4 /usr/lib/python2.5 /usr/include/python2.4 /usr/include/python2.5 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1
```

Is there an easy way to find out the location of a module in the PYTHONPATH. Something like:

```
>>> which (sys)
'c:\\Python25\Lib\site-packages'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do:

`modulename.__file__`

You will get a full path return of that exact module. For example, importing django:

```
>>>> import django
>>> django.__file__
'/home/bartek/.virtualenvs/safetyville/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

Edit: I recommend seeing the comments below for some good insight if you haven't had a chance to.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every module has the `__file__` attribute?
for example: 
`
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.__file__
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
    >>> import os
    >>> os.__file__
    'C:\\Python25\\lib\\os.pyc'

`

Comment: +1 Although this doesn't seem to work for `sys` as in the OP's example

Comment: It doesn't work for `sys` because `sys` doesn't come from a file at all: it's a built-in module. As such there is no sensible answer to `which(sys)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit kludgy but you can type `python pywhich os django PIL`:

```
import os, os.path
import sys

def pywhich(mod):
    for p in sys.path:
        try:
            if any(p.startswith(mod + '.py') for p in os.listdir(p)):
                return os.path.join(p, mod)
        except OSError:
            pass
    return "Not found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print arg, pywhich(arg)
```